# Ensuring only one instance of SWF open?

Tags: flash, instance, multiple-instances

I need to make sure that only one instance of a SWF is open at any one time on a computer, whether it is in 2 browser windows, or two different browsers.

How can I go about doing it?

I have so far thought of two potential solutions:

1) Using a Flash sharedobject - but since they never expire, if the user closes the browser window without calling my quit function to remove it, the remaining object will interfere with other new sessions. (Perhaps a random number and timestamp to identify the instance?)

2) Using a localconnection - a bit hackish, this relys on the swf detecting whether a Localconnection object is being used, and not loading if that is the case. But localconnections seems to crash at the slightest provocation, so I am a bit wary of using it.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need that?

Comment: what player version are you targetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe LocalConnection has one advatage over SharedObject solution - it allows global-scope LocalConnection names, though local SharedObjects are always stored per-domain, as far as I know.

As for SharedObject, the only option is to keep regularly updated timestamp in it, and check it every time your .swf runs.

So I'd opt for a simple LocalConnection-based solution, because it's quite straightforward, and I've never experienced any problems with LocalConnection.

```
public class LCTest extends Sprite
{
    public function LCTest()
    {
        var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
        lc.allowDomain("*");
        try
        {
            lc.connect("_myLCLock"); // underscore for global scope
            trace('not running, can init');
        }
        catch (e:ArgumentError)
        {
            trace('already running');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the SWF is only available from one location, I think Shared Objects are a safe bet. I don't think there's any need to worry about complicated sessioning, there should be a shutdown event you can catch even when the browser is manually closed. (Even if there isn't, I'm 99% sure that SOs are flushed on shutdown no matter what, so some workaround should be possible.)

However, Shared Objects are intrinsically linked to the location of the SWF, so a user could sidestep the above method by viewing a second copy of the SWF that they had saved locally, or uploaded to a different web server, or whatever. If that's a worry, and if the SWF would still work in such a situation, then I think LocalConnection is your only choice. But I've never found LC to be very reliable either. I don't know if it could be made bulletproof, but I think it's the only other option.

Comment: I'm not sure if the flash pluings for different browsers even have their SOs in the same location. So this might not work.

Comment: All flash players store their SOs in the same location.

Comment: Great answer. My friend is currently trying to implement this in his Flash game. If you don't mind, could you post more details regarding the SO method? Some directions, samples of working code, or references would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Note, there is an bug with LocalConnection
http://k2xl.com/wordpress/2011/04/30/localconnection-bug-in-flash-player/

Comment: Please can you summarise your blog entry and also you say that Adobe have responded and said that this is "by design" so it's not a bug is it?